# Opencv raspicam

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi2, haar-classifier

**Hi I would like to run this code to detect cars using raspicam on a raspberry pi B with OpenCV but encountered errors.**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars3.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**After running the code it returns**

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/pi/installopencv/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/pi/installopencv/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:8000: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

**Is the error happening because I'm using raspicam and "cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)" only work for webcam? I trying enabling V4L2 module but it didn't work as well**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the Raspberry PI camera module, use the [picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/) module to get the frames, not OpenCV'2 videoCapture module. In particular you want to install module with array support:

```
pip install "picamera[array]"
```

This will allow you to easily pass the frames to OpenCV.
There's a very good tutorial on how start from scratch [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/)
and here is the gist of it:

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

In your case, you may want to change the format from `"rgb"` to `"yuv"`.
This way, you can extract the `y`(luminosity) channel directly which will be your grayscale method. Hopefully you'll gain a small boost in speed not having to do the colourspace conversion (from BGR to grayscale) and fetching the frames from CSI (instead of USB).